In File Explorer, why did it started showing preview (thumbnails) of files on folder icons in Windows 11?
From new OS Windows 11 inside the file explorer, It started showing preview (thumbnail) of files on folder icons:

Is there any way to disable it?
One setting already tried from: “Folder Option > View > Always show icons, never thumbnails”
But it also disable images preview.

I found solution, which will may be useful to others:
Option 1 - Using Windows Settings:

Click on More Action (...) button in File Explorer, it will open Folder Options
Goto View Tab -> Tick “Always show icons, never thumbnails” checkbox


Note:
This option will also disable Folder Preview as well as Images Preview as shown below

Option 2 - Using Registry Edit:

Open RUN (Ctrl + R) and write “regedit.exe” and press enter
Go to Below Location:
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell
Add New String value and assign name “Logo” and it’s value as “c:\abcd.jpg”
Now reopen RUN (Ctrl + R) and write “cleanmgr.exe” and press enter
Select windows installed drive (c:) if not selected
Make sure “Thumbnails” is selected in the “Files to Delete” section.
Click on “OK” and refresh screen then you will be able to see files preview and not folder previews:



I think this is expected behaviour when an Icons View is selected in Windows 11 24H2. Have you tried changing the View option to List or Details? That may give you the display you need.
screen shot of File Explorer - View options

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@MarksComps If I change view option to list or details then it will also disable preview of images, I want to show image file preview (thumbnails) and only disable preview for folder icons.
